# Is the compiler generated constructor constexpr by default?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following code [compiles successfully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87eaf7b8444ada1d) with both *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 7.2.0* (compilation flags are `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`):

```
struct Foo
{
    constexpr operator bool() const
    {
        return false;
    }
};


int main()
{
    constexpr bool b = Foo{};

    (void)b;
}
```

Is such behavior of the compilers standard compliant? Note that adding any member (like `int i;`) to the `Foo` class [doesn't change anything](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b3d2b271036a52).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the implicit constructor is constexpr this case. In general, it depends on the sub-objects.

> [class.ctor]
>
> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (6.2)
>   to create an object of its class type (4.5) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration. The
>   implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed
>   by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (15.6.2) and an empty compound-
>   statement. If that user-written default constructor would be ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. **If that
>   user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a constexpr constructor (10.1.5), the
>   implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr**. ... [snip]

Relevant requirements of a constexpr constructor:

> [dcl.constexpr]
>
> - the class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> - for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and
>     base class subobjects shall be a constexpr constructor;

Comment: The implicitly-declared default constructor of `Foo` is indeed `constexpr` in OP's code, but that's irrelevant for the example as written, since `Foo{}` doesn't call any constructors; it's aggregate initialization. Neither would `Foo()` - that would be value-initialization that would perform zero-initialization, again without calling any constructors in the case of `Foo`. If a member `int i;` is added, as noted by the OP, the implicitly-declared default constructor is no longer `constexpr` (because it leaves `i` uninitialized), but everything else above still holds, so the code still works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. The default constructor that a compiler generates, and the trivial constructor

```
Foo() = default;
```

*both* enable you to write `constexpr bool b = Foo{};`, assuming all class members can be constructed `constexpr`. Note that if you had written

```
Foo(){}
```

then `constexpr` would *not* be allowed. (An important difference between `default` and a constructor provided with an empty body.)

Comment: Could you provide any reference to the text of the standard ?

Comment: See my comment to the other answer. Also note that a user-declared `constexpr Foo() { }` would be valid for the `Foo` in OP's code (no non-static data members), but not if we added a member `int i;` (it would still work for a member like `int i = 0;`).